# How can I change a JS, JSP, or XML file without having to restart my Tomcat server in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Whenever I start my Tomcat 5.5.29 server in Eclipse, it's status becomes "Synchronized."  If I save a change to a file of any type, it publishes that file and then says "Restart."  I used to be able to get it to synchronize again so that I could view the change without having to restart.  Any ideas?

I have checked to make sure Build Automatically is enabled.  I have tried disabling and re-enabling Auto Reload.  I have refreshed my projects.  I don't know what else to try.  Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the server has a .metadata setup, check that the server.xml's context, under server projects, is set to "reloadable = false".

After double checking this, right click on the server and click "Publish". This should force the new server conf files to go out.

Lastly, if that doesn't work, is your content statically avaliable(ie:localhost:8080/something.js)?

Comment: I already tried that.  It's functionally the same as disabling "Auto Reload" in the Modules pane of the Servers tab.

And yes, my content is statically available.

Comment: Is the "Publish Context To separate XML files" also checked? 

I recently noticed when I ticked that option, it started republishing when my web-app folder had any changes.

Comment: It wasn't checked.  After checking it, the problem still exists though =/